# I want added TouchEvent to my swipe script

Tags: javascript

I just made a script for my web app that open a link when you swipe left but its causing some issues, here is the code :

```
<script>

document.body.addEventListener("touchstart", startTouch, false);
document.body.addEventListener("touchmove", moveTouch, false);
 
var initialX = null;
var initialY = null;
 
function startTouch(e) {
  initialX = e.touches[0].clientX;
  initialY = e.touches[0].clientY;
};
 
function moveTouch(e) {
  if (initialX === null) {
    return;
  }
 
  if (initialY === null) {
    return;
  }
 
  var currentX = e.touches[0].clientX;
  var currentY = e.touches[0].clientY;
 
  var diffX = initialX - currentX;
  var diffY = initialY - currentY;
 
  if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
    // sliding horizontally
    if (diffX > 0) {
      // swiped left
      window.open("https://iblowit.com/wp-admin/Scan","_self");
    } 
  }
 
  initialX = null;
  initialY = null;
   

};
 
    </script>
```

and I need to edit it to swipe only if 2 fingers on the screen, I found this code but I don't know how to integrate it inside the first one :

```
function countTouches(event) {
  var x = event.touches.length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you had to add a simple verification before starting the touch event. You just have to check if there are 2 or more fingers pointing on the screen, if that's the case then fire the events otherwise just return a null.

```js
document.body.addEventListener("touchstart", startTouch, false);
document.body.addEventListener("touchmove", moveTouch, false);
 
var initialX = null;
var initialY = null;
 
function startTouch(e) {
  initialX = e.touches[0].clientX;
  initialY = e.touches[0].clientY;
};
 
function moveTouch(e) {
  if (initialX === null) {
    return;
  }
 
  if (initialY === null) {
    return;
  }
  
  // don't start the touch event if there is less than 2 fingers on the screen
  if( e.touches.length < 1 ) return;
 
  var currentX = e.touches[0].clientX;
  var currentY = e.touches[0].clientY;
 
  var diffX = initialX - currentX;
  var diffY = initialY - currentY;
  
  // Log the difference and display it on the span
  var span = document.querySelector("span#swipeDiff");
  if( span ) span.innerHTML = `${diffX}; ${diffY}`;
 
  if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
    // sliding horizontally
    if (diffX > 0) {
      // swiped left
      //window.open("https://iblowit.com/wp-admin/Scan","_self");
      console.log("Swiped left");
    } 
  }
 
  initialX = null;
  initialY = null;
   

};
```

```html
<span id="swipeDiff">-</span>
```

Comment: I changed my code to yours but it still swipes with one finger on screen, thanks for trying help

Comment: Oh I'm sorry i had to write the condition on the `touchmove` event not  `touchstart`. You can try now i fixed it!